# CKEditor, set default text color for newly entered text

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'd like to use ckeditor as an annotation tool and I like to set all new entered text to be a color (i.e. any new entered text is entered as red).

Answer (score -1):

ckeditor.applyStyle(new CKEDITOR.style({
                                    element: 'span',
                                    styles : { color : '#ff0000'} 
                            }));